# Prevent Javascript variable alteration & injection from Chrome Developer tool

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, xss

I built a javascript async code

```
    <script>



function sendVotes() {
        //some variables here that collects the number of votes a user input 
          var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            
          }
          };
          xhttp.open("POST", "async/vote", true);
          xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
          xhttp.send("id="+id+"&votes=" =votes);
         }
          </script>
```

I tried out the chrome debugging tool of which I got to notice that when script is paused on run time, variables can be changed and assigned new values e.g number of votes as in the sample code above

Is there a way to detect if the values of a variable is changed or a way to prevent such totally

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question then @Tibebes.M - Can you clarify what the question is about?

Comment: Oh wait, I understand it now. You're right - Retracted my vote

Comment: You can't prevent an experienced user from changing the variables from the dev tools - You must also validate the request parameters on the server and as a rule - You should NEVER trust the input from the user

Comment: Alon Eitan. Thanks but if for instance I integrate a payment gateway and after the payment gateway processes the payment (say $1000), then the amount is passed to a javascript variable of which we then send the amount paid via ajax. In this case, the value of the amount_variable can be changed to $30,000 through debugging after payment is successful before it is sent to server to input to the database. In this case, there is no way to validate on the server side how much was really paid since the value is sent through javascript & ajax to the server

Comment: That's why some (if not all) payment providers allow you to set the amount on the server, see [paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/) for example

Comment: Alon Eitan, in such case, how can you set the value of a variable on the server because if you working with ajax, you must pass the variable through javascript before it gets to the server... And thus, it can be manipulated

Comment: It's a bit complicated, but basically if the user wants to buy products X,Y and Z - You pass the IDs of those products to the server. Then, on the server, you create an order with those products (X, Y and Z), and since they are stored in the DB you should also have their price - The payment provider should then give you a **unique** order ID (Or a unique URL to the payment form) that you return back to the client. The last step would be to show the payment form to the client using the unique ID from the server (Using JS).

Comment: Thanks! Am understanding now a bit. Say the price is not in the database but rather the price is user generated (that is, you will have to get the price from the input and pass it to a variable), how can this be overcome